# update git submodule when submodule is changed

Tags: git, scripting, hook, git-submodules, gogs

i currently want to improve my workflow with git. I run a Gogs server on which there are several repos. One repo is software, the others are language files or translations.

Since the translators are not allowed to see the source code for internal reasons, I decided to include each language as submodules.

This works very well, it's very complicated only for me. I thought that as admin of the Gogs Server I might have the "power" to install a hook that automatically changes the submodules when there are new translations in them. I would be able to integrate the submodules into the different repos. The changes of the language files may be transferred directly from the submodule master to the master.

I'm afraid I have no experience with that. Could someone help me please.